# Application build failed cause of Lombok

Tags: java, gradle, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I've faced problem when building my project that uses Lombok after swapping to different git branch.
I get multiple exceptions generally of these two types:

1. for classes like

```java
@Setter(onMethod_ = @Autowired)
public class ClassA{

   private ClassC c;

}
```

I get

```java
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method onMethod_()
  location: @interface lombok.Setter
```

2. for classes like

```java
@Builder
public class ClassB{

}
```

I get

```java
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ClassBBuilder
  location: class com.example.application.ClassB
```

in methods like

```java
private ClassB.ClassBBuilder getBuilder(Object input) {
    //builder init
}
```

3. And after all I get `StackOverflowError`.

The problem is fixed after running `gradle:clean` -> `gradle:build`. But comes up again after swapping branch.
Some more information:
I'm using `Intellij Idea 2020.3.3 Ultimate Edition` and checkbox `"Enable Annotation processing"` is checked.
Here are some parts of my `build.gradle`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin

plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.19'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version '0.19'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE' apply false
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt-idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    maven { url = 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
//other dependencies
}
```

Does anybody know what could cause this problem?

Comment: Why there is underscore symbol  at the end of `onMethod_`?

Comment: does this happen when you try to build your project in intellij? The errors are expected if the lombok code generation for the new classes (from your new branch) has not been run.

Comment: I think the problem is related to your ide. try swapping a branch and do `gradle: build` without using intellij. Check if you still get the problem.

Comment: @Andrey, according to `Lombok` documentation underscore should be used with `JDK 8` and higher. See https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Setter.html.

Comment: @Mustafa, I get this error when trying to build with `Intellij`, build with `Gradle` goes fine, but sometimes I also get these errors, when I use `Bamboo`, so I don't think that is IDE-related.

Comment: @ImtiazShakilSiddique, building with `Gradle` goes fine, but when I launch `debug` in `Intellij` after that I still get these errors.

Comment: Okay, upgrading to Lombok 1.18.18 resolved the problem.

Comment: @AndreiYusupau please answer this question yourself and close it, as for the bounty, just don't reward it to anyone

Comment: Got same error with lombok 1.18.24 ;( 
Just change code in another maven sub module and the other module doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: I hope this helps someone, what I did is I used the `@Builder.Default` annotation on a field without having the `@Builder` annotation on the class. It produced the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in a newer version of Lombok. Please update the Lombok version to 1.18.18 and it will fix the issue.

Comment: This is so stupid and frustrating. I can not import lombok 1.18.18 (because my organization creates  a wrapper before we can use open source). I feel frustrated to fix such stupid issues with framework or IDE (instead of actual work). I wish when will this world becomes smooth for software developers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to upgrade your lombok dependencies to the latest version.